# Extract column positions that differ rows with duplicated pairs in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
master <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), B=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,8),C=c(5,2,5,7,7,5,7,9,7,8),D=c(1,2,5,3,7,5,9,6,7,0))
```

As you can see I have 4 columns `A,B,C,D`. What I want to achieve is to create a new dataframe which will include the duplicated pair-rows between `A` and `B`, the index of rows where this duplication happens,the column names that make those rows different (`C,D`,or `C` and `D`) in a third column and the column position of those column names that make these rows different.

The desired output should be something like:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   A [?]
#     A     B     n locs  different position
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>    <int>
#1     2     3     2 3, 4  C, D     3,4
#2     4     6     2 7, 8  C, D     3,4
```

As you can see the duplicated pair-rows are different by columns C and D which are in the 3rd and 4rth position of the master dataset respectively. As you can see below the only thing that needs to be added is the column position based on the initial `master` dataset.

```
#code
library(tidyverse)
master %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   group_by(A, B) %>% 
   filter(n() > 1) %>% 
   summarise(n = n(), 
            locs =  toString(rn),
            Different = case_when(n_distinct(C) > 1 & n_distinct(D) > 1 ~ 'C, D', 
                                  n_distinct(C) > 1 ~ 'C', 
                                  n_distinct(D) > 1 ~ 'D', 
                                  TRUE ~ 'Same')) 

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   A [?]
#     A     B     n locs  different
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>    
#1     2     3     2 3, 4  C, D     
#2     4     6     2 7, 8  C, D
```

Comment: Can you extend the same logic of `Different ` column with `case_when` for `position` column as well ? but for output instead of `'C, D'` you replace it with `3, 4` and so on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data.table, which has the convenient symbols `.N` for group size and `.I` for row number. All that's left is to check which columns are different, which you can do by `sapply`ing over them and checking the number of unique elements with `uniqueN`.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(master)

out <- 
  master[, .(n = .N, 
             locs = .(.I), 
             different = .(names(.SD)[sapply(.SD, uniqueN) != 1]))
         , by = .(A, B)] %>% 
    .[n > 1]

out
#    A B n locs different
# 1: 2 3 2  3,4       C,D
# 2: 4 6 2  7,8       C,D
```

Then you can get `position` using `match(different, names(master))`, using `lapply` to go one row at a time.

```
out[, position := lapply(different, match, names(master))]

out
#    A B n locs different position
# 1: 2 3 2  3,4       C,D      3,4
# 2: 4 6 2  7,8       C,D      3,4
```